# error while exporting database in mysql

Tags: c#-4.0, mysql, mysql-workbench

During exporting the mysql database structure and data to *.sql file.
I wound get the full insert query for a table

> Opened Mysql work bench.
>
> clicks Manage Import/Export  then choose server to connect.
>
> Admin tab opened there i choose a schema and Export Self contained file and then give a                  file path.
>
> then clicks start Export. there i got error message

i don't get the full insert query records for a table in that schema .

Why i getting this this error pls tell me how to get the full insert queries for that database schema.